# Cannot install anything using Pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, easy-install, part-of-speech, textblob

I am trying to install this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textblob-aptagger and it says to use this code  - but I do not know where to use it (command line and Python console do not work):

```
$ pip install -U textblob-aptagger
```

I installed easy_install and pip using exe files from 
    http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

So when I use the command:

```
$ pip install -U textblob-aptagger
```

in the Python console I get this error:

```
  File "<console>", line 1
  $ pip install -U textblob-aptagger
  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where should I use this installation command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run the executable from the command line, but since it's not in your PATH, you'll need to supply the full filepath. On my system pip is installed at `C:\Python27\Scripts`, so the command I would use to install textblob-aptagger would be `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install -U textblob-aptagger`. Yours will likely be located in a similar if not identical location.

Comment: Worked. So the in  $ pip install -U textblob-aptagger the "$" stands for file patch.

Comment: No, it signifies a shell. But most tutorials are written for *nix, where pip is typically installed to the PATH, so just typing "pip" works. The Windows installer doesn't do that. Also, if you would mark my answer as correct, that would be great.

Comment: Thanks. It allowed me to mark the correct answer now, so i have done that since i asked the question 5 minutes ago.